# Message Sending in ionic 3 Apps is not working

Tags: ionic3

I am working on ionic 3 project in which i am trying to send the message on button click 
Here is my code for sending the message:-

```
send()
{  
 this.sms.send("342423423","Hi")
 .then(()=>{
   console.log("The Message is sent");
 }).catch((error)=>{
   console.log("The Message is Failed",error);
 });
}
```

But every time i clicked on button is showing me error message, i am  not understanding how i can achieve to send the message. Is there any permissions required to be enable how to do that?

Thank you guys in advance

Comment: Does adding permissions work?

Comment: For me it did not work

Answer (score 0):

For android permissions use ionic native Android Permissions

ref. https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/android-permissions/

android permission ref. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission

ex.

```
this.androidPermissions.checkPermission(this.androidPermissions.PERMISSION.SEND_SMS).then(
  result => {
    console.log('Has permission?',result.hasPermission);

    if(result.hasPermission){
      this.sms.send("342423423","Hi")
      .then(()=>{
      console.log("The Message is sent");
      }).catch((error)=>{
      console.log("The Message is Failed",error);
      });
    }
  },
  err => this.androidPermissions.requestPermission(this.androidPermissions.PERMISSION.SEND_SMS)
);
```

and you can use this also ref. https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/sms/#hasPermission

```
this.sms.hasPermission();
```

Comment: I have file A and file B i am writing sms sending logic to file B so where should i include my permission logic in file A? because it is my starting file

Comment: yes request the permission before user start using the app. the fair way

Comment: I have added my permission logic to File A and when i console sms.hasPermission it is returning TRUE....but when i click on send sms it printing error message

Comment: var mobNo = 342423423;
this.sms.send(  mobNo.toString(),  'Hello world!');

Comment: i tried above solution but still it is executing catch block code ...do we need some third party assistance to send text message?

Comment: have no idea about sending sms to other user using any third party, third parties are available to send bulk sms, otp, etc but does not have a mobile number.

Comment: The problem is that android manifest does contain permission for SMS SENDING. Please add line below to android.manifest o make it work for android permission



<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />